# Filter objects from a list

Tags: java

The following line of code gets a list of objects via repository and creates a map.

```
 Map<String,String> shippedAccountMap = repository.findByAccountNumberIn(outboundAccountNumberDistinctList).stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Omg::getAccountNumber, Omg::getMacAddress));
```

There are scenarios when getMacAddress can be equal to null.

1. I want to filter out those objects (with mac address == null) and to store them as is in a fallout list

   ```
    List <Omg> fallout
   ```
2. I want to remove all the mac address null's in order to be able to create the map.

How can I do this with Java 8?

Thank you

Comment: use method 
       Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate) 
before collect.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, if I understand correctly, you want to get two distinct data structures from a single list. Of course, it can be done by simply construct a stream twice:

```java
Map<String, String> shippedAccounts = omgs.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.getMacAddress() != null)
    .collect(toMap(Omg::getAccountNumber, Omg::getMacAddress));

List<Omg> fallouts = omgs.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.getMacAddress() == null)
    .collect(toList());
```

But maybe you want to achieve this in a single pass, for whatever reason.

#### Java ≥ 12

That can be done with `Collectors::teeing`. It 'tees' a stream into two distinct collectors.

First, you'll need to create a result container, to put the two collected results in:

```java
public record ResultContainer(Map<String, String> shippedAccounts, List<Omg> falloutList) { }
```

Then you could do this:

```java
ResultContainer rc = accounts.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.teeing(

        // 1st collector: filter out null mac addresses, and then map to accNo -> macAddr
        filtering(e -> e.getMacAddress() != null, toMap(Omg::getAccountNumber, Omg::getMacAddress)),

        // 2nd collector: leave only null mac addresses, and then put into list
        filtering(e -> e.getMacAddress() == null, toList()), (map, list) -> new ResultContainer(map, list)
));
```

#### Java 8

In Java 8, where `teeing` is not available, you could create a result container which acts as kind of collector:

```java
public class ShippingDetails {

    private Map<String, String> shippedAccounts = new HashMap<>();
    private List<Omg> fallouts = new ArrayList<>();

    public void accept(Omg omg) {
        if (omg.getMacAddress() != null) {
            shippedAccounts.put(omg.getAccountNumber(), omg.getMacAddress());
        }
        else {
            fallouts.add(omg);
        }
    }

    public ShippingDetails merge(ShippingDetails other) {
        shippedAccounts.putAll(other.shippedAccounts);
        fallouts.addAll(other.fallouts);
        return this;
    }

    // Plus getters for both fields
}
```

Each element passes through `accept`, which then puts it into the correct structure, based on whether `macAddress` is `null`. At last, multiple such collectors are then joined, which occurs when the stream runs in parallel.

```java
ShippingDetails sd = omgs.stream()
    .collect(Collector.of(
        ShippingDetails::new,
        ShippingDetails::accept,
        ShippingDetails::merge
    ));
```

Comment: Didn't Collectors::teeing appear in java 12?

Comment: @IlyaSazonov Yes, that is correct. I have updated the question to also include a Java 8 version.

Answer (score -1):

first

```java
List<Omg> fallout = repository.findByAccountNumberIn(outboundAccountNumberDistinctList).stream()
                    .filter(e -> e.getMacAddress() == null)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

second

```java
 Map<String,String> shippedAccountMap = repository.findByAccountNumberIn(outboundAccountNumberDistinctList).stream()
.filter(e -> e.getMacAddress() != null)                    
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Omg::getAccountNumber, Omg::getMacAddress));
```